# check/remove permissions to access laptop camera

Tags: permissions, camera, accessibility

I wanted to read a QR code and used an online site. The site asked me permission to use the camera which I granted.

I'm now a bit worried, how do I check the permissions and if, necessary, remove them?

Comment: This would be controlled through the browser that you were using. You should be able to see something in the "security" section of the options, with the ability to revoke permission.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which supported release?

Comment: @waltinator yes, using ubuntu, Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS